# Most efficient way to truncate a string using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, string, performance

I was looking at some code and started thinking about the most efficient way to truncate a string (in this case, a URI) using `preg_replace`.

First off - I realize that using `preg_replace` in the first place might be overkill for this task, that it may be needlessly expensive, and that it might better be handled using PHP's string-friendly functions such as `substr`. I do know this.

That said, consider these two different Regular Expressions:

```
$uri = '/one/cool/uri';    // Desired result '/one/cool'

// Using a back-reference
$parent = preg_replace('#(.*)/.*#', "$1", $uri);

// Using character class negation
$parent = preg_replace('#/[^/]+$#', '', $uri);
```

By default I would assume that in the former case, creating the back-reference is going to be more expensive than not doing so, and therefor the 2nd example would be preferable.  But then I started wondering if using `[^/]` in the 2nd example might be more expensive than the  corresponding `.` in the first example, and if so, how much more?

I prefer the first example from a readability standpoint, and since we're splitting hairs I lean towards choosing it between the two (after all, there's value in writing readable code too).  May just be my personal preference though.

Thoughts?

Comment: You seem to understand what you're asking, so why not setup a benchmark? My gut also assumes the negation is less expensive, but that's just my _gut_. I have no data to support it. Make some data!

Comment: Note that the second version can be made more efficient using a possessive quantifier (suppressing backtracking): `#/[^/]++$#`

Answer (score 2):

I also would measure running time of both options. This information from the docs may help too:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.performance.php

> If you are using such a pattern with subject strings that do not contain newlines, the best performance is obtained by setting PCRE_DOTALL, or starting the pattern with ^.* to indicate explicit anchoring. That saves PCRE from having to scan along the subject looking for a newline to restart at.

So, `$parent = preg_replace('#^(.*)/.*#s', "$1", $uri);` may speed the first option. The second one would not need this setup:

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)
>
> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the
>   pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it,
>   newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s
>   modifier. **A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline
>   character**, independent of the setting of this modifier.

Comment: This would only make a difference for strings which do not match the pattern at all. If the OP knows that every string (s)he wants to truncate **will** contain at least one slash, then the match will be found on the first trial anyway.

Comment: The optimization suggested is to avoid splitting the string by newlines and trying the pattern on every one.

Comment: Ah right, sorry, fair enough. I kinda missed that point. Although URIs will rarely contain line breaks. But in general that's definitely a good point then.